# Autolayout + size classes: Possible to distinguish between different iPhone X and other devices?

Tags: ios, autolayout, size-classes

While autolayout and size classes are a great way to define different constraints and thus different layout for different devices like iPhone and iPad it seems that it is not possible to automatically distinguish between devices with (iPhone X, Xs, etc) and without (iPhone 8, 8 Plus, 7, etc.) safe areas.

**Is this correct?**

One of my ViewControllers uses a ScrollView as root view. The content shows some information and below a button which is positions near the bottom of the screen to be easily accessible.

While this works great on iPhone X like devices, the button is not visible without scrolling on older devices without safe areas.

I would like to use size classes to automatically distinguish between the two device types to position the button in different ways. However, all iPhone devices have compact width and regular height. So, is there no way to use size classes to layout for different iPhone devices. Do have to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, at the moment there's no way to distinguish devices with top and bottom padding from the others using only Size Classes.

This because the "Safe Area" is present also in other iPhones (iPhone 8, 8 Plus, 7), but it's equal to the leading and trailing margins of the view controllers (safeAreaInsets = 0).

Apple is trying to make our layouts indipendents from the safeAreaInsets value.

I agree with you that this would be a really helpful implementation.

Comment: static let iPhoneX = (UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && max(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height, UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width) == 812)

Comment: Yes we know, but you're not using Size Classes, also this takes only in account the iPhone X and not XS, XR, etc

Comment: Size classes cannot be used for this. For Iphone xr replace 812 with 896 & for iphone xs (its same as iphone x)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! @Friend I know that this can be solved in code but the question was if there is an easy solution to do this in IB with size classes or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following class ,

Add to your project and change constant directly from storyboard.

I have not update this since long time so you may need to use according to your requirements

```
//
//  ConstraintHelper.swift
// 
//
//  Created by Prashant on 29/08/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Prashant. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation

import UIKit


@IBDesignable
public class LayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint {

    // MARK: 3¨5


    @IBInspectable
    public var 3¨5_const: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {

            if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 480 {
                constant = 3¨5_const
            }
        }
    }


    @IBInspectable
    public var 3¨5_multip: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 480 {
                self.setValue(3¨5_multip, forKey: "multiplier")
            }
        }
    }


    @IBInspectable
    public var 3¨5_active: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 480 {
                isActive = 3¨5_active
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: 4¨0


    @IBInspectable
    public var 4¨0_const: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 568 {
                constant = 4¨0_const
            }
        }
    }


    @IBInspectable
    public var 4¨0_multip: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 568 {
                self.setValue(4¨0_multip, forKey: "multiplier")
            }
        }
    }


    @IBInspectable
    public var 4¨0_active: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 568 {
                isActive = 4¨0_active
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: 4¨7


    @IBInspectable
    public var 4¨7_const: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 667 {
                constant = 4¨7_const
            }
        }
    }


    @IBInspectable
    public var 4¨7_multip: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 667 {
                self.setValue(4¨7_multip, forKey: "multiplier")
            }
        }
    }


    @IBInspectable
    public var 4¨7_active: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 667 {
                isActive = 4¨7_active
            }
        }
    }
    // MARK: 5¨5


    @IBInspectable
    public var 5¨5_const: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 736 {
                constant = 5¨5_const
            }
        }
    }


    @IBInspectable
    public var 5¨5_multip: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 736 {
                self.setValue(5¨5_multip, forKey: "multiplier")
            }
        }
    }


    @IBInspectable
    public var 5¨5_active: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 736 {
                isActive = 5¨5_active
            }
        }
    }
}
```